# I can't figure out why a sentence diagrammer says that a question that sounds correct cannot be diagrammed

Tags: grammar, diagramming

I am helping a student study for the TOEFL exam and I used the website [1aiway.com](http://1aiway.com/) to diagram sentences for me to check that they are correct. The website won't recognize sentences with adjective clauses that begin with the relative pronoun "who" though, nor their reduced forms. 
For example, the website cannot recognize the sentence "The Smiths, who live in the southernmost suburb, must drive more than an hour to get to work," nor the sentence "The Smiths, living in the southernmost suburb, take more than an hour to get to work."

Sometimes I've been able to figure out why a sentence that I think is supposed to be correct is not (about 20-40 percent of the time), but not always, and the examples I wrote here are straight from the book.

I want to try to find out why the diagrammer can't diagram them, and I found this website and I want to ask folks here for any ideas you may have as to why this sentence that seems correct comes up as not being a complete sentence according to the sentence diagrammer.

Thank you,

Iulia

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's more a matter of the software in question being insufficient to handle the myriad complexities of language than the sentences being ungrammatical.

Comment: This is really a question about writing a program to understand "natural language".  There are some programs that are pretty good at this, but this one apparently in not.  (Plus, as noted, some sentences require some "creativity" to diagram.)

Comment: It's really about warning people not to trust grammar sites on the web. Especially if they advertise themselves with diagramming. That shows they're incompetent; Reed-Kellogg diagrams don't work for many kinds of sentences, as the OP's experience shows.

Answer (score 4):

To give a diagram for a sentence is to propose a theory about the derivation of that sentence.  The correct derivations of sentences of human languages are incompletely known by anyone at all, to say nothing of a computer program.  It's completely unsurprising that the program you dealt with doesn't know how to deal with some sentences.  I know more than a program does, and there are many sentences whose structure puzzles me.

The examples of appositive constructions you give are especially difficult for a knowledgeable diagrammer.  In his book *The Syntactic Phenomena of English*, McCawley discusses the relevant evidence and concludes that an appositive relative clause associated with the subject of a sentence is not part of the subject, and so it cannot be diagrammed using the usual sort of hierarchical tree structure.

Comment: Oh, thank you for your reply. I know that language changes with time and what seems write and wrong to a native speaker changes, but I wanted to use that program to make sure I didn't write anything that is incorrect according to the rule book so I used it to check my sentences, but even though I realize the program is not perfect, I did not rule it out because it helped me catch some errors that I did not think were wrong before. I'm glad to hear an answer to this question that confused me, so thanks again to both of you guys!

Comment: @Iulia: You might want to recheck those sentences that you were told were errors. If they can be wrong about one thing, they can be wrong about others. And there are many, many "errors" that aren't errors at all. Greg's right; you'd appreciate McCawley's discussion, and his book is the best English grammar you can hold in one hand.